# Reason for setting relationships among entities in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity

After learning about relationships between entities in Core Data. I don't see the real reason for setting up relationship between two entities. They can be connected separately if one of the entities contains a property that can hold another entity by having a property of type `NSManagedObject`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong ) NSManagedObject *AssetType;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a concept you must understand: **Core Data is not a database but it is an object graph manager and, as a second functionality, offers persistence (e.g using for example a Sqlite store).**

Said this, if you have two separated entities and you need to retrieve values based on the conditions that belong to the other entity, you need to run two requests and filter the results in memory. On the contrary if you set up a relationship you can just create a request wih a specific predicate and let Core Data to retrieve the correct results for you.  In addition, through relationships you can access objects that belong to another entity as simple as accessing a property object. For example, the following snippet says that based on `entityA` I can access a property calles `someRelationship` that allows to retrieve one (or more) entities of type `EntityB`. If `someRelationship` has been set up as to-many you'll receive one or more `EntityB` entities.

```
entityB = entityA.someRelationship;
```

The real advice is to think in terms of **objects graph**!!!

Further reference: [Core Data Overview](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-overview.html) by objc.io.

**Update 1**

The other big advantage is that relationships allow you to take advantage of deletion rules and, through inverse relationships, you are able to maintain the integrity of your graph.

See [Relationships and Fetched Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html).